# Vue3, Webpack, yarn build fails, yarn serve OK

Tags: webpack, babeljs, vuejs3, yarn-v2

I'm full stack developer but this error beyond my ken.

`yarn serve` success.

CSS files tailwindcss and dasiyui. Both minified CSS.

yarn build:

```
yarn run v1.22.19

    $ vue-cli-service build
    
         ERROR  Error: CSS minification error: Cannot read property '0' of undefined. File: css/app.fa30ae87.css
        Error: CSS minification error: Cannot read property '0' of undefined. File: css/app.fa30ae87.css
            at .../node_modules/@intervolga/optimize-cssnano-plugin/index.js:106:21
            at async Promise.all (index 0)
        error Command failed with exit code 1.
        info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

**Versions:**

- Vue 3.2.41
- Babel 4.5.13
- ESLint 6.7.2
- Babel EsLint 10.1.0
- NodeJS v14.20.1
- @vue/cli 4.5.13
- webpack 4.46.0

I've used all settings other projects all run fine.

Comment: Isn't vue generating some kind of cache? Because `css/app.fa30ae87.css` looks quite like something generated for cache purposes.

Comment: I believe so or build CSS the production, that's my guess anyway.